# DAC extension field always null

Tags: acumatica

I have a nullable bool DAC extension field (PXDBBool) of the SOShipment class that is always throwing an error when inserting into the SOShipment table:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'UsrSignatureRequired', table
>   'Acumatica_6_10_1219.dbo.SOShipment'; column does not allow nulls.
>   INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.

I've tried an attribute of PXDefault(false) on the extension, setting a local var explicitly to false that is returned by the property getter, and setting it explicitly in the FieldDefaulting handler.  The only method that seems to work is setting it explicitly in the FieldDefaulting handler, but the handler is called too soon (before the shipment's order list is initialized). I also tried setting it explicitly in SOOrderShipment's RowSelected event because I'm trying to set the new field value based on whether there are multiple orders fulfilled by the shipment, but then the new value doesn't take and I still get the null error. Note: I've also tried to use a non-nullable bool, but get the same results.

There must be something simple I'm missing. Any idea why PXDefault(false) isn't working for me and it seems to always be null when inserting?

Using v6.10.1219

Here's the DAC extension class:

```
  public class SOShipmentExtension : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.SO.SOShipment>
  {
      #region UsrSignatureRequired
      [PXDBBool]
      [PXUIField(DisplayName="Signature Required")]
      [PXDefault(false)]
      public virtual bool? UsrSignatureRequired { get; set; }
      public abstract class usrSignatureRequired : IBqlField { }
      #endregion

      #region UsrSignatureRequiredOverride
      [PXDBBool]
      [PXDefault(false)]
      public virtual bool? UsrSignatureRequiredOverride{ get; set; }
      public abstract class usrSignatureRequiredOverride: IBqlField { }
      #endregion
   }
```

Comment: you mentioned the field is nullable but the error clearly indicates the field is not nullable. Look at your project xml to confirm your field is showing nullable="true". I typically make the extension fields nullable simply for existing records. Ex: <col name="UsrSignatureRequired" type="Bit" nullable="true" /> If not then just edit your xml to add nullable="true" and save to database then re-publish. Also, would be good to include your field code in your question as it is defined in your project.

Comment: Tony, can you post the full code of your DAC? I suspect there’s a slight error preventing PXDefault from working as it should...

Comment: The db column is a non nullable bit. The DAC extension property is a nullable bool.  I just looked at the project xml, and the xml node you mention isn't in there, or mention of nullable. My guess is that this is because it is in an extension library.  I could recreate the column in case something got out of sync when converting to extension - I've had that happen before.

Comment: I just recreated the column in Acumatica and moved it to the extension library.  I did notice in the project xml that it says AllowNull="True", though.  I removed that attribute and saved.  However, the same error is being thrown.  I guess next I'll probably change the bit column back to nullable (which is the default) to see if that helps anything.

Comment: Changing the bit column back to nullable seems to have resolved the error, but now of course I'm getting nulls in my column which I don't want, and is the real problem. Why would a PXDefault(false) ever be null? I'm never setting it null, but I do set it to true/false in the SOOrderShipment_RowInserting handler. Back to debugging.

Comment: I commented out my SOOrderShipment_RowInserting handler so I knew that wasn't causing anything.  I set a breakpoint in my SOShipment_RowPersisting handler and when I check the value of my extension field, yes, it is null. What is nulling it out?

Comment: Added DAC extension code to original post.

Comment: The only thing I can get it to work is to set the value explicitly in the RowPersisting.  I'll go with that for now until I know why it's getting nulled out.